# Passing UITableViewCell Data from Firebase populated array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I have a tableview that loads database info from Firebase and the image pulls from Firebase storage with my hardcoded directory/file.

I want the value of cell.videoID.text so that I can pass it to another viewcontroller via Segue.  I just can't seem to get the value of cell.videoID.text when the cell is clicked and have tried all sorts of ways from this and other sites.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return vehicleList.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
    let vehicle: VehicleModel

    vehicle = vehicleList[indexPath.row]


    cell.videoID.text = vehicle.id
    cell.neworusedLabel.text = vehicle.neworused
    cell.yearLabel.text = vehicle.year
    cell.priceLabel.text = vehicle.price
    cell.makeLabel.text = vehicle.make
    cell.modelLabel.text = vehicle.model
    cell.packageLabel.text = vehicle.package
    cell.colorLabel.text = vehicle.color

    // Get the image from storage container

    let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    let imagePath = "tmpDir/tmpImage.png"
    let tempImageRef = storage.child(imagePath)
    tempImageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 600 * 600) { data, error in
        if error == nil {
            cell.lblView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    return cell
}

var valueToPass:String!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
    print("currentCell")

    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

//  valueToPass = "Trying to get the videoID"

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: And your `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: Back up one line before the performSegue and that's where I'm stuck.  I can't get the variable before the performSegue...so the code in the prepareForSegue isn't relevant for this (but it works on the other 10 vc's I have in this project).

Comment: Try this `valueToPass = vehicleList[indexPath.row].id`

Comment: That was it!!!  I missed the fact that I called it videoID on one side and id on the other!!  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

My answer was:  valueToPass = vehicleList[indexPath.row].id

Thanks to Kosuke above in the comments!